# Can I set Tag code in a Javascript file, to be Linted with the CommonJS standards

Tags: eslint, commonjs

I am writing some Common JS. This is causing problem because I'm working in ES6 so while the word LET will compile fine when I'm running my tests it needs to be VAR in CommonJS.

Is it possible to use a esLint tag or something to say check certain block of code with different rules.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can tag specific files with

```
/* eslint-env commonjs */
```

used as a comment in the file

Comment: Now that you've removed the CouchDB reference from your question, it is the right answer. I'd remove my down-vote, if I could.